# How to call a view from another in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, pycharm, wtforms

So the SignUp 1 function connects to a html file, this part is all fine and the user can submit the form. However, once this form is validated, i'd like to call the SignUp2() function, which should connect another html file with a form. However, once the user submits the form (in the SignUp1 function), I get an error called: **werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'SignUp2'.**

Please could you tell me how I can call the SignUp2 function from the SignUp 1 function. Thankyou.

```
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def SignUp1():
    form = UserForm()
    SchoolCode = None
    FirstName = None
    Postcode = None
    Phone = None
    ConfirmEmail = None
    Password = None
    AddLineOne = None
    AddLineTwo = None
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        first_name = form.FirstName.data
        last_name = form.LastName.data
        postcode = form.Postcode.data
        phone = form.Phone.data
        email = form.Email.data
        password = form.Password.data
        add_one = form.AddLineOne.data
        add_two = form.AddLineTwo.data
        user_id = AddUser(first_name, last_name, postcode,     phone, email, password, add_one, add_two)
        Parent_id = user_id
        SignUp2(Parent_id)
    return render_template('SignUp.html', form=form)


def SignUp2(Parent_id):
    form = Child1Form()
    c1_FirstName = None
    c1_LastName = None
    c1_Year = None
    return render_template('ChildSignUp.html', form=form)
```

Comment: You haven't decorated the second function and, to be honest, I don't understand the question.

Comment: Why do you expect a single request to render two templates?

Comment: Sorry @roganjosh I tried to explain it as best as I can

Comment: Nonoonooo I expect each function to open a html page

Comment: How? In different tabs? I don't see how it is supposed to work otherwise. You want to render two templates as far as I can tell. You could use AJAX and update a <div> but I'm lost on what this is supposed to do (And I'm not suggesting you're wrong in what you're trying, I just really don't follow)

Comment: I'm just trying to open another template once the user has submitted the form on the previous html page, but I also need to pass in this value 'Parent_id'

Answer (score 0):

You need to give SignUp2 a route as well, and then you should redirect, rather than trying to call it directly.

(Note, all those assignments to None are pointless, you don't use any of those variables anywhere.)

```
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def SignUp1():
    form = UserForm()
    ...
    if form.validate_on_submit():
       ...
        return redirect(url_for('SignUp2', Parent_id=Parent_id))
    ...

@app.route('/signup2', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def SignUp2(Parent_id):
    ...
```

Comment: I'm assuming that this works because it's from you, but what happens to `'SignUp.html'` here? That was the original, rendered, return.

Comment: Hello. Thankyou for your help. I made the changes that you suggested, and then the interpreter was telling me that 'redirect' and 'url_for' are not defined. So I imported them from Flask and this was no longer a problem. However, now I get the error "TypeError: url_for() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given".

Comment: After the form is submitted, nothing happens in the SignUp.html

Comment: Should I re direct to SignUp2.html from the SignUp.html.